# How will "winning" be percieved?

Tags: american-english, british-english

If I use the phrase "winning business" as a byline to a logo. How will it generally be percieved?

1) Like a winning business

2) Like the act of winning business

3) Doesn't make any sense to have that as a byline

Comment: With the status quo, the second meaning will be inferred.  If it were "a winning business," then the first one.

Comment: It's ambiguous. A logo give little context to sort out the meaning.

Comment: Donald Trump is a "winner" (just ask him).  How is he perceived?

Comment: @HotLicks Trump is going to become the new "Hitler" in the sequel to Godwin's Law isn't he.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On it's own, with no context, it could mean either, and this ambiguity may make it attractive as a slogan: some people reading it would understand that it was ambiguous but that both meanings were desirable and it was therefore a clever play on words.

That said, if people had to pick one meaning, I think most people would think of "the act of winning business".